# Can water at 0 degrees Celcius and 1 atm have a range of different cooling abilities?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, cooling

Imagine we have two 1L containers of water, both at 1 atm, both at 0 degrees C.  However, container 1 is at point (b) in the heating/cooling curve below, while container 2 is at point (c) in the heating curve below.

[image]

Then when mixing these two containers of water with two 1L containers of water at say 50 C, the resulting mixes would have different temperatures, right?

What I'm getting at is that water at 0 C can have a range of different values of specific heat, and those different values would result in the water being able to cool other things differently, right?

Perhaps to achieve liquid water with different amounts of specific heat one container would be just thawed and the other would be just melted?

Answer (score 0):

Point B corresponds to a 1 kg chunk of ice at 0C, and point C corresponds to 1 kg of liquid water at 0 C.  It takes 333 kJ of heat to melt the ice and move from point B to point C.  What temperature do you think mixing 1 kg of liquid water at 0 C with 1 kg of liquid water at 50 C would end up at.  Do you think that mixing 1 kg of ice at 0 C with 1 kg of liquid water at 50 C would end up at the same temperature?  Do you think that all the ice would even melt?

Comment: So if I add 150 kJ of heat to that block of ice at 0 C, what do I have in my container?  Do I have half water and half ice?  Or do I have all ice that's closer to melting?  I guess the question is: are there internal, non-visible changes going on inside the ice at 0 C before it turns into water?  Or is every kJ of heat visible as either a temperature change or a state change?

Comment: You have half water at 0C and half ice at 0C